# Setting filterValues from HTML input in a Marketo API with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, rest, marketo

I am trying to pass text strings into an array so that they can be used as a filterValue in Marketo's REST API via PHP.

Users submit their form while listing each element every line. That goes into an array. I can successfully convert this to an array. For example, if the HTML form was filled

```
item1
item2
item3
```

and I print_r() the output, it looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => item1 [1] => item2 [2] => item3 )
```

So that sems to be working. Let's say I save that as $output. However, if I pass $output to $leads->filterValues, it does not work. I've tried simply making an array and passing it directly or calling a function like so:

```
$leads->filterValues = $output;
```

or

```
$leads->filterValues = setValues();
```

Neither of which work and the API call fails. However, if I hardcode these items in like so

```
$leads->filterValues = array("item1", "item2", "item3");
```

Everything works just fine then, and the API call goes through with those values. What's going on here? Is there a way I can pass the input data and set that to the filterValues array?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the URL from the data from the form had way more characters then the URL from hardcoded data when using var_dump() despite being identical. Use

```
        $url = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $url);
```

before curl_init($url) to cleanse it of the hidden characters.